# how can i redirect mapUnknownRoutes to a parent

Tags: hottowel, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

This is what i have i a child routing( from work --> index.js)

```
.map(acceptedTypes).buildNavigationModel().mapUnknownRoutes('code404', 'code404');
```

how can i redirect it to the parent `code404` ?

my folder looks like this.

```
 App |
     viewmodels |
                shell.js
                code404.js
                home.js
                work  |
                      index.js
                      office.js

     views     |
```

error:

```
View Not Found. Searched for "views/work/code404
```

this will work but will breack the page

```
.mapUnknownRoutes(function () { return router.navigate('#code404'); }, 'code404');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it.  'Users' matches my route.

```
  childRouter.mapUnknownRoutes('Users', '#membership/Users');
```